# Function to remove archive sidebar for custom taxonomy?

Tags: customization, taxonomy, sidebar

I have a custom taxonomy/custom post category and I'm trying to write a function, which removes the sidebar from the archive pages, only when there's a (custom) taxonomy match. The match part isn't the issue, but I'm unable to silence WP's `get_sidebar()` (triggered by `arhive.php`). The best result I got, removed not only the sidebar, but also the footer and admin header menu... which is a bit too much.

Does anyone know how to disable `arhive.php`'s `get_sidebar()` via `functions.php`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom archive template for your custom taxonomy. so if your taxonomy is 'XYZ' , its archive page will be taxonomy-XYZ.php. Now in this custom archive page for your custom taxonomy, you can choose to add /remove sidebar as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much @FiazHusyn for breaking my obsessive search "spell", trying to find a function-based method! Your answer confirms that the template approach is indeed the best approach. Sigh, now I can finally start to untangle the knots in my head. I'll post my approach as an answer.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @FiazHusyn, I went for the custom taxonomy archive template approach. On top of that I gave the custom taxonomy archive template, it's own custom sidebar template. Here's how to do that:

1. Copy/paste your theme's `archive.php` and rename the copy to `taxonomy-your_taxname.php`;
2. Copy/paste your theme's `sidebar.php` and rename the copy to `sidebar-your_taxname.php`;
3. Open `taxonomy-your_taxname.php`, look for `get_sidebar()`, replace it with `get_sidebar('your_taxname')` and save/close the file;
4. Upload `taxonomy-your_taxname.php` and `sidebar-your_taxname.php` to your theme's root folder on your server.

That's it! You should now be able to customize both the custom archive and sidebar templates, relating to your custom taxonomy.

**Don't want a sidebar?**

In case you don't want a sidebar for your custom archive template, simply remove/comment out `get_sidebar();` in `taxonomy-your_taxname.php`.